# StackOverFlow Exception from WebJobsBuilderExtensions while running Azure function locally

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have written `Azure` function which is throwing `StackOverFlow Exception` in the below code from class `WebJobsBuilderExtensions` in the namespace ` Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs

```
 services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IHostedService, JobHostService>());
```

[image]

Here is my `Startup` class

```
[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(Startup))]
namespace FuncApp
{
public class Startup : IWebJobsStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .Build();

        builder.Services
            .AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config)
            .AddSingleton(serviceProvider => serviceProvider)
            .AddLogging();
    }
}
}
```

Note: The function was working fine few weeks back, and suddenly stopped working without any changes to the code.

**Reproduction steps**

1. Create an azure trigger function using Visual studio 2019 or 2022
2. Add `Startup` class and add above code
3. Run

Boom!

Comment: What dependencies does `JobHostService` have?

Comment: How can I  find it?

Comment: Look at its constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started working after removing the below line

```
  .AddSingleton(serviceProvider => serviceProvider)
```

not sure how it was working before and what the change is under the hood!

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2926#issuecomment-1280167555

Answer (score 0):

- The issue is because of the `serviceprovider` in the `startup.cs` class.
- So instead of setting up it like

```
.AddSingleton(serviceProvider => serviceProvider)
```

First create the service provider and then start the singleton service.

Now to create the service provider first create a service collection.

```
 var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
```

Now use `buildserviceprovider` function to create a service provider.

```
 var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
```

complete code :

```
  var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

            var provider1 = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider(true);
            builder.Services
                .AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config)
                .AddSingleton(provider1)
                .AddLogging();
```

[image]